# How to manage shared bootstrap data accross multiple projects

Tags: java, grails, bootstrapping

I have 3 web-projects that use the same database and same models. These systems require partly the same bootstrap data in the database in order to run properly. All Systems share library code that will read the data from database and update it according to the bootstrap data in the code (add new, remove unused, update changed). Every application will perform this when they start and most of the time nothing needs to be done since the data is already correct. This data is also used by some of the integration tests.

The problem is that when some of the common data needs to be changed, then all 3 applications needs to be re-deployed with the new bootstrap data because otherwise they will bootstrap with the old data in case they are restarted (server reboots for example).

I'm looking for the best way to manage shared bootstrap data for multiple projects.

Comment: Why not extract the common data out completely, and have that be responsible for the changes? Then you'd have 3 projects that *don't* share bootstrap data, and it'll be a lot easier.

Comment: this sounds like its going in the right way, but what do you suggest to do with the extracted data, who or what should manage it?

Comment: I don't know enough about your project to be able to give exact advice, but instead of having several components "battle it out" on who gets to do what with the data, I'd really look on creating a separate component for only handling that data, and having the 3 former fight buddies be dependent on that component to work with the data.

Comment: yeah this is what i figured also

Answer (score 1):

You could create a plugin that contains a service that does what you need and include the plugin in all projects. Then simply call the plugin service within each bootstrap.

Comment: I think this approach still has the need of doing a re-deploy for all the projects if the data changes. At the moment the data is shared with a plugin already.